# Using libraries with ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying out Visual Studio 2015 Preview creating a new MVC 6 project.  I would like to add existing MVC libraries but anything I add to the project.json results in a warning in the references for ASP.Net 5.0 and/or ASP.NET Code 5.0.  In truth I haven't found any existing libraries or packages on nuget (tried DefinitelyTyped too) that will work.

I'm guessing that with all the structure changes, especially the removal of System.Web, none of the existing libraries will work.  Can anyone confirm this or provide a way to force them to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "MVC controls"? MVC doesn't do controls, that's WebForms.

Comment: Did you mean Tag Helpers (`<li><a controller="Home" action="Index">Home</a></li>`)? [Scott Hanselman describes them](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5VNextWorkInProgressExploringTagHelpers.aspx), and the code is available on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my current study of Visual Studio 2015 preview , you are right that we can not use many existing library with ASP.net MVC 6.

Following is possible reason.

1. Some of then library only support core framework but it does not support other. So if you Target your library to only one framework some of them will work.
2. Many of Owin packages will not work or required some work around as AppBuilder interface get changed.
3. One of the reason that you have given is "System.Web". They replace with new structure.
4. Even if you build library in vnext and if you want to add it to your project ( not from same solution) then you have to publish nuget package locally and have to add in another solution.

I have  just answered some question that it related to this. Please have a look at that.

[Add existing assembly to an mvc 6 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582305/add-existing-assembly-to-an-mvc-6-project/27664366#27664366)