# Add reference to an existing assembly (source not included)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm evaluating the possibility to migrate a four years old MVC3 application to the next MVC6. I have figured out everything for the migration (sessions, security, etc.) except for one thing, importing a commercial assembly I use for exporting data to Excel, Word and PDF, I don't have the source code, and in Visual Studio 2015 there is no way to add reference except for those projects already in the solution or using NuGet. I don't have a NuGet package, since this commercial assembly is from pre-NuGet times, so, how can I add a reference to this assembly to a MVC6 Project?, and btw, I'm not interested in core-clr by now, so no need for multiplatform support.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, fixed, what I did is to create a NuGet package for the assembly using the info here:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

and here:

[Add existing assembly to an mvc 6 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582305/add-existing-assembly-to-an-mvc-6-project/27664366#27664366)

Then I added it to the dependency to the Project.json file.

Thank you.